# I want to do make an and-gate but why do I get high when my swich is off?

Tags: digital-logic, falstad

I want to do make an and-gate but why do I get high when my swich is off?
[image]

Comment: Your picture suggests it is only really small (10 nV) and not high at all.

Comment: Are you asking why the test point on the upper input is showing 4.596 V?

Comment: No, I mean why I even get 4.596 V when my swich is off. I want to make an and-gate with one Voltage and 4 resistors.

Comment: You don't? The output is the TP on the right, not the TP in the middle.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Tanner Swett exactly

Comment: @TannerSwett I need to do as this pitchure https://www.google.com/search?q=transistor+and+gate+circuit&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiVtcG_lLLuAhVQwioKHdkgC8IQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=transistor+and+gate+&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQARgAMgQIABATMgQIABATMgQIABATMgYIABAeEBMyCAgAEAUQHhATMggIABAFEB4QEzIICAAQBRAeEBMyCAgAEAgQHhATMggIABAIEB4QEzoCCAA6BAgAEB5Q0MhOWM_dTmCv8E5oAHAAeACAAViIAekDkgEBNpgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1nwAEB&sclient=img&ei=fyQMYNX5NdCEqwHZwayQDA&bih=617&biw=1366&rlz=1CAEZTK_enSE879#imgrc=Lq2PAadJL0IopM. I got 2 swiches, 2 10k resisor, 100 resisor and 1000 resistor to ground and a voltage (5 V)

Answer (score 0):

Add a load resistor to the top BJT, ie. a resistor from the emitter to the ground. But Andy is right in that the output is actually low/off.

Comment: It is not my output that is the problem. My input on the transistorn at the top are sendning a high when my swich is off.

Comment: The top BJT is floating high via its base-collector parasitic resistance because the bottom BJT is off and hence it appears as a high impedance. Just add a resistance, e.g. 10k to the top BJT's emitter to ground.

Comment: I can not add anything. I can just remove things like 100 reisitorn and my switchs and voltage.

Comment: @Eleinor "It is not my output that is the problem." – Then you don't have a problem. The output is the only thing that matters. It's okay to have 4.596 V in the middle of the circuit while both inputs are off.

Comment: @TannerSwett but i will send a 1 to one of the input which is not the meaning

Comment: @Eleinor I don't understand what you're trying to say. Both inputs are off and the output is low. Therefore, the AND gate is behaving correctly in this picture.

Comment: @TannerSwett If you look to the top test point it is showing 4.596 V which is not low even when I am sending a 0

Comment: @Eleinor That doesn't matter. The top test point doesn't need to be low. The gate is behaving correctly. There are no problems here.

Comment: @TannerSwett Okey, thanks! Can I come back if I gets more problem?